# Как работает Tuple в LINQ?

Tags: c#, сортировка, linq

решал вот такое вот задание по сортировке, смысл в том, что дан список слов, нужно найти самое длинное слово из этого списка, а из всех самых длинных — лексикографически первое слово.

Задание я решил, но не совсем пониманию, как Tuple отрабатывает с LINQ и почему сложность такой конструкции O(N) в отличии от сортировки O( N * logN)

Можете рассказать как это происходит поподробнее или дать ссылку статью/книгу, где это было бы разъяснено?

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetLongest(new[] { "azaz", "as", "sdsd" }));
        Console.WriteLine(GetLongest(new[] { "zzzz", "as", "sdsd" }));
        Console.WriteLine(GetLongest(new[] { "as", "12345", "as", "sds" }));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string GetLongest(IEnumerable<string> words)
    {
        return words.Min(w => (-w.Length, w)).w;
    }
```

Comment: Тапл сравнивается по значению его членов, то есть сначала сравнивается его первый член, среди одинаковых первых - второй и т.д.

Comment: Т.е. Он внутри себя создает промежуточную коллекцию, которая определяется первым условием и потом к ней применяет второе условие?

Comment: Если в классе несколько полей - это коллекция? Нет, вот и с таплом то же самое. Но да, сравнивающий механизм проходит по членам тапла как по коллекции.